# Why IFrame does not load on a single click on container div?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, credit-card, cybersource

**Background:**

Working on Cybersource Credit Card integration with React app. Need to show Masked card number coming from API response upon tabbing out (`onBlur`) of field.

**Flow**

1. Created a container-div in which IFrame gets loaded and I enter CC number. On `blur` event, doing API calls for validation and getting the masked card number (if successfully validated).
2. Upon setting `maskedCardNumber`, component gets re-rendered and shows the maskedCardNumber in the container-div. At this point I see in Elements tab, IFrame is *gone* which is perfectly fine to me. Now in my container div there is no IFrame but a masked card number.

*I want to change CC number*

3. I click on *input alike div* and masked card number gets removed because of `setMaskedCardNumber("");`. ( Not each character one by one but all in once as we do not have that card number). Till this point everything is fine.

**Problem**

After removal, it should show new Iframe because I am calling `loadIFrame();` like I did for initial Iframe loading but weirdly it does not show until I click **AGAIN**. YES!! you read it right. I need to click AGAIN to load and IFrame which is very weird for me.

**Tried so far**

1. `useState()`,
2. `useReducer()`,
3. to make `<label>{maskedCardNumber}</label>` inside container-div.
4. Changing conatiner-div `<div>` to `<input>`

**Relevant code**

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (apiKey) {
      loadIFrame();
    }
  }, [apiKey])


const loadIFrame = () => {
let flex;
flex = new Flex(apiKey);
let microform = flex.microform();
let number = microform.createField('number', {
    placeholder: 'Enter card number'
});
number.on('load', () => {
    number.focus();
});
number.on('blur', () => {
  
    //transient token call
    microform.createToken({}, function(err, token) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            setCardError({
                ...error,
                token: "Please enter valid CC number"
            })
        } else {
            setCardError({
                ...error,
                token: ""
            });

            //permenant token call
            setMaskedCardNumber(JSON.parse(atob(token.split('.')[1]))["data"]["number"]);
            dispatch({
                type: orderActions.GET_CC_TOKEN,
                transientToken: JSON.parse(atob(token.split('.')[1]))['jti'],
                callbacks: {
                    success: (ccToken) => {
                        updateCardDetail({
                            type: "token",
                            token: ccToken
                        })
                    },
                    failure: (err) => {
                        console.error(err);
                        setCardError({
                            ...error,
                            token: "Please enter valid CC number"
                        })
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    })
});
number.load('#number-container');
}

    <div id="number-container" className="form-control" onClick={() => {
        setMaskedCardNumber("");
        loadIFrame();
      }}>
        {maskedCardNumber}
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem I see here is basically the response to your `setMaskedCardNumber()` call returns after the iFrame is loaded due to its async nature.

Try putting this effect

```
  useEffect(()=>{
    if(maskedCardNumber === ""){
      loadIFrame()
    }
  }, [maskedCardNumber])
```

and remove `loadIFrame();` from `onClick()` handler

this will make sure whenever you empty the cardNumber state, iFrame is loaded when it is successfully emptied.

**UPDATE:**

We can make use of single `useEffect`.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (apiKey && !maskedCardNumber) {
      loadIFrame();
    }
  }, [apiKey, maskedCardNumber])
```

With this we can make sure to load IFrame only if apiKey present otherwise do not try to load because IFrame is dependant on apiKey.

Comment: Simply awesome bro. Slight change in plan. Updated your answer. Thanks

Comment: Hi Zain , which library you are using for cybersource in react js ? I am integrating cybersource in React JS no library found which can use Flex ?